# How to find foreign key meta data in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model defined like:

```
class DatasetPvtdata3(models.Model):
    commodity = models.ForeignKey('DatasetSctg', related_name='+', to_field='description', db_column='commodity')
```

Now at runtime, if i get the strings `DatasetPvtdata3` (model name) and `commodity` (field name), how can i find their corresponding foreign key model name and the corresponding column (`DatasetSctg` and `description`)?

The use case is that i first need to run a query on `DatasetPvtdata3` model and then use that output to filter `DatasetSctg`.

Comment: Do you wish to carry this out in a django view? Where are the strings coming from? Are they POST or GET data from a template?

Comment: The strings are stored in a separate adapter table, which acts as an adapter between an old model fields to this new one. All this happens in a backend logic class instantiated and called by a view.

Comment: You can use the django orm to query the models.meta atribute list and then get name description ect

Comment: The meta examples i can see on django site are all at Model Level. I am not sure how to look for field level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a model name as a string, I think the safest way to get the corresponding class is to use the [contenttypes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) framework. Something like this should work, using your real app name:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
ct = ContentType.objects.get(app_name='my_app_name', model='DatasetPvtdata3')
my_model = ct.model_class()
```

If you're not using the content types framework, in theory you can get the model from `globals()` if you have imported the model into whatever module contains the lookup code, but I wouldn't go that way unless I had to:

```
from my_app_name.models import DatasetPvtdata3 
my_model = globals().get('DatasetPvtdata3')
```

To get the field object, use `my_model._meta.get_field_by_name('commodity')`. That returns a tuple, of which the field is the first element.

Once you have the field, `field.rel` will be a class representing the relationship. `field.rel.to` will be the model that the FK is to (`DatasetSctg` - the class itself, not a string containing its name) and `field.rel.field_name` will be the `to_field` name (the string `description`).

Comment: This was precisely what i needed. Thanks

Comment: Great answer! Seems it is now no longer `app_name=` but `app_label=`.

Answer (score 0):

I have such scenario. I have a list where I show fields from basic table and some other fields from Foreignkey-related tables.

And I need verbose names, information about null=True/False of the fields and so on.

I have found that for the basic table I can read

```
Model._meta.get_field('name').verbose_name
```

And for the fields located inside a related table:

```
Model._meta.get_field(<foreignkey>).target_field.model._meta.get_field('name').verbose_name
```

I don't know if this is at least partially the answer for this question. However maybe it can be a help for somebody.